# Unable to turn in Minecraft, but can move forwards and backwards

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

My son logs on to Minecraft, chooses the hard drive as storage, chooses a world, but when he enters he is unable to *turn* his character. He can move forwards and backwards, but unable to turn. This is the second time I've downloaded it, and it worked last night; however, when the game was played today the issue has resurfaced.

Answer (score 9):

While I can't find an official "known issue" report, there are [numerous](https://m.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1utgfz/strange_happenings_xbox_360_version/) [threads](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-xbox-360-edition/mcx360-discussion/2004036-cant-turn-in-minecraft) online discussing an issue in the Xbox 360 edition of Minecraft where all the game options have their values initially set to zero. Try going into the game's settings menu, and check to see if the controller sensitivity is set to zero. If it is, turning the controller sensitivity up will solve the problem.